# no provider for ngControl [FormControl] Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular. While the official tutorial has worked quite well for me, I am stuck with the 'hello world' of Reactive Forms. I am following https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. I have created a new component, in an other wise working project, to make an input text box using ReactiveForm. The template html is as follows:

```
    <div>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" [formControl]="name">
        </label>
    </div>
```

The component class looks as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-party-worker',
  templateUrl: './party-worker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./party-worker.component.scss']
})
export class PartyWorkerComponent implements OnInit {
  name = new FormControl('');
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The error in the browser reads something like this.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for NgControl ("
    <label>
      Name:
      [ERROR ->]<input type="text" [formControl]="name">
    </label>
  </div>"): ng:///ViewsModule/PartyWorkerComponent.html@3:6
```

And yes, I have imported ReactiveFormsModule. My angular version, if it is revealed by `ng --version` is as follows

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.5
Node: 11.1.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.5
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.5
@schematics/angular          7.0.5
@schematics/update           0.10.5
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

I fail to understand as to what is it that I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 98):

To make this work you'll have to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `@NgModule` which is the `ViewsModule` as your question suggests. As `FormControl` is exposed as a part of `ReactiveFormsModule` and NOT the `FormsModule`.

```
...
import { ReactiveFormsModule, ... } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., ReactiveFormsModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class ViewsModule {...}
```

Comment: At the cost of repetition, let me state that I have already done that in the app module. Imported both ReactiveFormsModule, and FormModule since ab initio. Also played with their order. But to no avail.

Comment: Is the `PartyWorkerComponent` a part of your `app.module`?

Comment: `PartyWorkerComponent`  is a part of `ViewsModule`

Comment: Then the `ReactiveFormsModule` should be added to the `imports` array of `ViewsModule`

Comment: It can be seen from the error `ng:///ViewsModule/PartyWorkerComponent.html@3:6`

Comment: @yurzui, thanks a lot for pointing that out. I overlooked that. :)

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for pointing it out. Just saw the comments after posting my answer and independently discovering the same by fluke. And also Sidd for painstakingly trying to find the fault.

Answer (score 29):

For Angular 11, it should be:

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
             FormsModule,
             ReactiveFormsModule      
        ]
```

Comment: I was missing FormModule in my .spec file.... and this made me realize I needed this along with ReactiveFormModule.

Comment: I might be wrong, but to my understanding `FormsModule` needs to be imported to support the [(NgModel)] while `ReactiveFormsModule` the [formGroup] (and related) inputs

Answer (score 20):

For anyone using [Storybook.js](https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-angular/) and seeing this error. Don't forget to import the above mentioned into your story too.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

moduleMetadata({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for slipping `Storybook.js` into this answer, I didn't know about it, but now I do :)

Comment: Actually, you should import the forms module as well:
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
and then import it as well

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue and it turns out I had a custom form control and forgot specify either [(ngModel)] or [formControl] when I used the control.

Comment: Damn, I went straight to the modules and was looking everywhere in my imports for what I was missing, and it simply turned out the parent component wasn't providing it a `formControl` to begin with (`formControlName` in my case).

Answer (score 7):

There are possible reasons for this error.

**1. Import `ReactiveFormsModule`**

Import `ReactiveFormsModule` module where your `component` is declared i.e.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ......
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ]
})
export class YourModule { }
```

**2. Initialize `formControl`**

Add `formControl` to your input i.e.

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="yourControl">
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for troubling whosoever may have given it a thought. It turned out that there were two modules in my application and **the AppModule was not where my component resided**! The ReactiveFormsModule was missing in the module which mattered. Added the same and problem solved.